# Peer Package Error with Codelyzer when installing breeze

Tags: angular, breeze, angular5

I installed @angular/cli which gave me v1.5.2

Using "ng new ...", I generated a new app. In the package.json that came with the new app, I can see that I've not got all of the Angular 5.0.0 packages.

Next, because I want to use breeze, installed the breeze-client and breeze-bridge-angular packages which gave me v1.6.3 and v4.0.1 respectively.

When I did the install, I got peer errors with codelyzer. Did I do something wrong in my installs or will I need to install other dependencies manually?

```
>>npm install breeze-client breeze-bridge-angular
npm WARN codelyzer@3.2.2 requires a peer of @angular/compiler@^2.3.1 || >=4.0.0-beta <5.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN codelyzer@3.2.2 requires a peer of @angular/core@^2.3.1 || >=4.0.0-beta <5.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've seen a bunch of places with both breeze and angular where I get peer dependency issues. It didn't seem to affect any of the basic usage of either of those frameworks, so I don't know if it's much of an issue. So I don't know what they're for, but at least I was able to move on.